# Constructing the center of a circle, straightedge only. Variants on the Poncelet-Steiner Theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

The Wikipedia [Poncelet-Steiner Theorem entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poncelet%E2%80%93Steiner_theorem) says: *Any Euclidean construction possible with straightedge and compass can be done with straightedge alone, provided that at least one circle with its center identified already exists on the plane.* I already know this to be true as I've worked the constructions and seen the proof.

What interests me and what this question is about are some of the other claims made in the article - variants on the Poncelet-Steiner theorem. As it turns out the one circle with its center identified isn't strictly necessary. Alternative criteria exist, including:

1. Having two concentric circles without a center.
2. Having two distinct intersecting circles without their centers.

I have also worked these constructions and am satisfied. They are fairly straightforward.  Proofs attributed to Detlef Cauer.  They culminate in the construction of the center of the circle, thus reducing the scenario to the original Poncelet-Steiner hypothesis. No issue here so far.

But still other claims are made, between the Wikipedia, [Wolfram's MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerConstruction.html), and other sources.  Namely,

3. Two non-intersecting circles (without centers) but with an arbitrary point on the centerline (collinear with the centers).
4. Three non-intersecting circles.
5. I've also seen reference to two congruent circles with an arbitrary point on the meridian between them being sufficient. (thats a point on the perpendicular bisector of the segment connecting centers)

All three of these variants supposedly end in the construction of a circle's center point.

Another claim is that

6. Any arc of the circle with the center identified is enough (equivalent to the Poncelet-Steiner). Francesco Severi apparently gets credit.

But none of claims 3-6 have adequate citation.  I've followed these citations to their inevitable dead-ends and I'm still left without proof or demonstration. For all of them.

I've tracked every source down, and the sources that they reference as well, right down to the bitter end, even accessing academic databases and checking out books at the library. I even bought one $100 book that seemed promising.  All they do is cite one another and vaguely refer to "his work", sometimes even quoting one another nearly verbatim.  But never a proof. Never a construction.

One site I came across claims to provide a construction for one of these claims and to their credit they do show a lot, but it doesnt actually show the complete construction. In fact they use the phrases "you get the idea" and "a few hundred more lines to draw", leaving it to my imagination to fill in the gaps. Thats not even counting the fact the text is poorly worded and the images are improperly labeled.

And yes, I've tried proving them myself but unfortunately my intuition with geometry isn't that great. I also have no delusion about how complex or time-consuming these constructions might be.

> Does anyone know how to prove variants 3-6? Or provide a citation to actual literature that explicitly proves or demonstrates these?

Because, as it stands, it would appear that these are claims made out of thin air with no real backing; assertions that have skimmed by without peer review. And, if so, that needs to be corrected. I have faith that these claims are true but I desperately want to learn them. The best of the best geometers I know cant tell me where to begin.

---

After a few years of searching I finally managed to put in the proper keyword combination to find something that lead me to something else.  A book titled "*Über die Konstruktion des Mittelpunktes eines Kreises mit dem Lineal allein*", by Detlef Cauer, supposedly has the proof for three non-intersecting circles case (bullet point 4).  Unfortunately the book is written in German and its hidden behind your standard academia (anti-education, anti-peer review, knowledge hording) paywall.

> A translation of this texts proof(s) would be great, but that covers only one of the cases, leaving three still outstanding.

Comment: Appreciate the constructive edits, @Blue.  You write goodly.

Comment: What's the meridian in #5 ?  Is it the line halfway between the 2 circles?

Comment: @brainjam Yes sir.  Perpendicular bisector of the segment connecting centers.

Comment: I hesitate to even start an answer.  You are asking for a detailed proof of 4 propositions. You refer to a site that explains #3 in some detail (I suspect enough to do the entire construction if you have the background), but are unsatisfied.  You have a reference for #4 but imply that you want somebody to dig it up and translate if for you (translating math from German yourself is not insuperable even if you don't know the language).  In my opinion, you are asking for an answer that would fill a chapter of a book.  I respectfully suggest you narrow the scope of the answer you are requesting.

Comment: That said, I think it's a really interesting topic.  I've learned a lot just looking around on the web for background.

Comment: Why did you make your previous comment then? Seems rather a waste of time if youve already decided not to answer.  I wasnt strictly asking for "detailed proofs of 4 propositions". I was asking for at least a link or a citation to useful information. And I quote "Or provide a citation to actual literature that explicitly proves or demonstrates these?".  Id be content with ONE detailed proof. One useful link.  Ive been working on this for 5 years and its taken me this long to find one German reference to one of the propositions.

Comment: Why are these propositions made in wikipedia and elsewhere if no one can prove it? I asked ABOUT four propositions in one questions because they are intimately related, not because I expect one person to do all the work.  Put in however much work you feel comfortable putting in. I just want to make progress in this endeavor, and not be criticized by unhelpful people for having the nerve to ask. This is the status quo on this site. I didnt ask you to learn German either; I assumed someone might already know it.

Comment: Although youre not wrong that I lack the formal background for some of these higher geometric topics (projective geometry, namely) the immediate assumption that I dont is someone insulting. You think its not worth your time because Im too stupid to understand anyway, is what youre implying. Ive been studying this topic for 5 years. Quite a bit longer than you apparently have been. I made it clear that the site was poorly written, not that it was "above me".

Comment: Thats coming from someone who thinks its reasonable proposition I learn German to solve a math problem. But Im asking for too much work of you?! Astonishing! Im not asking for a lot of work. If youre competent enough in this subject to GIVE an answer, thus someone I WANT to hear from, then youre getting quite a bit for all the work thats involved in embedding a link, which is all I really asked for. The information has to already exist somewhere in a useful form. If you want to write more than that, then great.

Comment: Can you give a reference that mentions #5?

Comment: I've added some more references in my answer, including one for the three circle case (in English)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of these constructions are fairly complex, and I'm not going to give them in any detail.  OP has asked for information that will help move the ball forward. I'll give some comments and references, and will add detail or clarification or corrections where requested.  I have not vetted any of the constructions in every detail.  I'll number the claims to match the numbering in the question.

3. Two non-intersecting circles with a point on the join of the centers. The site referred to by OP is most likely http://mathafou.free.fr/pbg_en/sol100a.html. The construction is the topic of [C. Gram. A remark on the construction of the centre of a circle by means of the ruler. Math. Scand.,
   4:157–160, 1956.](https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10466/8487)
4. Three non-intersecting circles.  Apparently in *D. Cauer. Uber die Konstruktion des Mittelpunktes eines Kreises mit dem Lineal allein (Berichtigung).
   Math. Ann., 73(1):90–94, 1912 and 74(3):462–464, 1913 (German)*.  If you can find Smogorzhevskii's *The ruler in geometrical constructions*, the construction for three circles not in the same coaxial system is given at the end of the book.
5. Two congruent non-intersecting circles with an arbitrary point on their radical axis.  Use the following construction to get the line $X_{11}X_{12}$, which joins the circle center.  After that use the same construction as in 3.  In the figure, givens are in blue, and the points are numbered in order of creation.  The four chords (e.g. $X_1X_2$) are polars of $P$ and X_6.

[image]

6. Any arc of the circle with the center identified. See Chris Impens' [Geometry without compasses](http://ci47.blogspot.com/2013/11/geometry-without-compasses.html)
7. Bonus case. Two non-congruent non-intersecting circles with an arbitrary point on their radical axis.  As for case 5, build the points $X_1,\dots,X_5$.  Let $X_E$ be the intersection of the lines $X_2X_3$ and $X_1X_4$.  Then line $X_5X_E$ goes through the centers.

Akopyan and Fedorov's [Two circles and only a straightedge](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.02562) gives a useful overview of some of these topics.

Comment: Respect for going through with an answer after getting a vigourous response for misunderstanding what OP wanted when it wasn’t clearly stated in the question body

Comment: How did you even find these resources in such short notice, given that the topic is completely new to you? I am impressed.  I havent vetted these for usefulness to my own ends... but this is far more than I previously had.  If I solve any of the propositions I will eliminate them from my list and... if necessary... repost a new question eventually.

Comment: Google was helpful for 3 and 6.  And 5 and 7 weren't difficult because 3 indicated you needed to find the center line, and because I studied some related constructions last year.  I'm not sure why you think the topic is completely new to me.  I was aware of Steiner constructions, but never paid much attention to them. If 4 relies on finding center lines there may be some hope of figuring that out without finding Cauer's paper...

Comment: @CalvinKhor Dont be a part of the problem. Dont deliberately antagonize or escalate when youre not even a part of the conversation. I made my question quite clear. Its not my fault this "community" look for any excuse at every turn to justify not giving an answer.  I appreciate brainjam for actually answering the question, but at no point was clarification from me ever necessary.  I should never have to justify asking a question.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you if you think that anyone was asking you to "justify asking a question". The math content of your question is crystal clear but I too struggled to understand what you wanted. Here are some great clarifications that came from your comments, which you could try to include in future questions: "Id be content with ONE detailed proof. One useful link."; "I [don't] expect one person to do all the work. Put in however much work you feel comfortable putting in. I just want to make progress in this endeavor."; "embedding a link, which is all I really asked for".

Comment: @CalvinKhor Perhaps I miss the point of a Q&A forum, but I thought it was well understood that people pose their math questions (which you say you understood clearly), and the discussion begins at a community level on how to solve it. At what point is it explicitly or implicitly stated that one person *should* do all the work? Is that a given? Does it really need to be said? Most of the time the questioner is expected to show their (usually fruitless) work before anyone cares to work a problem. I thought my frustration at not making any progress in nearly 4 years was also understood?!

Comment: At least well enough to convey that ANY help would be appreciated.  In any case, I really dont know how it bares any relevance to the content of the question itself, which should stand on its own clearly. Or, again, put another way, why I need to justify my question.  Im not your school teacher here to delegate work to you.

Comment: I agree in the abstract but that just isn’t how Math SE is set up. In particular, this is not a ‘forum’. The expectation that answers are to be more or less complete is a grey area that not everyone agrees on, so if your question has any meat on its bones I think it best to say what you are looking for. There have been many discussions over what constitutes an Answer on this site. Are hints enough? How big a hint? Are you allowed to post partial progress? Should I answer the best version of the question, or point out the naive issues in the question formulation(missed trivial counterexample)?

Comment: Although you would have accepted a link only answer, this is an explicitly stated reason for voting to delete an answer. Although you accepted this incomplete answer, I have seen people say ‘thanks but this doesn’t answer my question, I’m looking for XYZ’. So I don’t think you can make such a clean distinction between the mathematical issue at hand, and what you would consider a satisfactory response. I think it is reasonable that Answers should be made in an attempt to be Accepted by the OP. This is a social question, and not always obvious when the question is not clear cut eg homework.

Comment: Finally I don’t know why you think that is equivalent to ‘justifying a question’. This is a very odd phrase that smells of an accusatory tone. Maybe you think someone was asking you one of those canned comments eg ‘what have you tried?’ but it was not the case. More communication is helpful, that shouldn’t be surprising. The fact is I didn’t think that ‘any help at all would be appreciated’. That’s two people who thought different from you, take it however you may.